# spring boot custom Validator annotation not working on parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, hibernate-validator

I have created a new annotation to validate my parameters on a controller:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValueValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidValue {
    String message() default "Invalid value";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

This is my validator:

```
public class ValueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidValue, String> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidValue constraintAnnotation) {
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (s.contains("hello")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("hello is not valid");
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/extraction-date", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Operation(summary = "Find  customers by extraction date")
public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> findAllCustomersByExtractionDate(@RequestParam @ValidValue String value)
{
    System.out.println(value);
    return null;
}
```

my controller is annotated with:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/customers")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Controller
@Validated
@CrossOrigin
@Tag(name = "customer-controller", description = "Controller managing operations related to customers ")
```

I also have an Advice controller, which I'm intending to use to catch the thrown exception:

```
@ControllerAdvice()
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    /**
     * @param ex a Throwable
     * @return a responseEntity with a descriptive message and some other information
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorMessage globalExceptionHandler(Throwable ex) {
        LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
        return getErrorMessage();
    }

    /**
     * @param ex a Exception
     * @return a responseEntity with a descriptive message and some other information
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorMessage globalExceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
        LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
        return getErrorMessage();
    }

    /**
     * @param ex      an InvalidInputException
     * @return a responseEntity with a descriptive message and some other information
     */
    @ExceptionHandler({InvalidInputException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorMessage invalidInputExceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
        LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
        return getErrorMessage(ex, ErrorCode.INVALID_INPUT_ERROR);
    }

    /**
     * @param ex      an ResourceNotFoundException
     * @param request the request from the client
     * @return a responseEntity with a descriptive message and some other information
     */
    @ExceptionHandler({ResourceNotFoundException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorMessage resourceNotFoundException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
        return getErrorMessage(ex, ErrorCode.RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    /**
     * @param ex thrown exception
     * @param errorCode to be returned to the client in message
     * @return the error message with all attributes
     */
    private ErrorMessage getErrorMessage(Exception ex, ErrorCode errorCode) {
        return new ErrorMessage(
                errorCode.code,
                new Date(),
                ex.getMessage(),
                errorCode.description);
    }

    /**
     * @return the error message with all attributes
     */
    private ErrorMessage getErrorMessage() {
        return new ErrorMessage(
                ErrorCode.INTERNAL_ERROR.code,
                new Date(),
                "Error while proceeding a joinPoint, unhandled exception: see log messages for more details.",
                ErrorCode.INTERNAL_ERROR.description);
    }
}
```

This is what I get after calling the method from postman:
[image]

What I got on the console:

```
INFO |2021-11-17T08:51:48,898|88D0657C2A8042FDBD32C05E96280791| [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.obs.dqsc.api.controller.CustomerController - Entered in CustomerController.findAllCustomersByExtractionDate(hello)
hello
INFO |2021-11-17T08:51:48,903|88D0657C2A8042FDBD32C05E96280791| [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.obs.dqsc.api.controller.CustomerController - Exit from CustomerController.findAllCustomersByExtractionDate(..); Execution time: 2 ms;
```

The dependencies I have in my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Please could anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: exactly that was the problem, I've read in this article https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/ that we don't need starter-validator if we have already starter-web included, but on another article I've found the opposite here : https://www.yawintutor.com/how-to-validate-request-parameters-in-spring-boot/  so now it's working correctly. thank you!

Comment: (probably) it was true in the past, but evolved! ;-) easy fix! +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was missing the start-validator to make it work, so all what I had to do is to add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I was missing @Validated annotation, it started working after I added it on the class where I was using My Custom Validator